# How to grow LVM partition to include newly released partition (now unallocated space)

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I had a Windows partition and I nuked it in favor of a VirtualBox VM.  Now I could use the extra space it was occupying. LVM2 is in use on the Linux side but the Windows partition which has since been removed pre-dates the LVM setup. The space in question is to be added to the `/home` partition. I've created an admin user who has a home dir that is not in `/home` so that I can log in as him and get this done. Procedure? Do I need to mess with the volume group? Do I need to use `fdisk` first or can I use a `pv*` command?  This situation seems more complicated than gparted or lvm (the GUI tool) can manage.

Additional info:

```
dude@machine:~$ sudo lvs 
  LV     VG        Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  home   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao--- 214.87g                                           
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao--- 191.39g                                           
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-a----  31.94g                                           
dude@machine:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500106780160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976771055 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xca18e148

Note: Below sdb3 is physical and sdb5 logical but it's the same space. 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb3       526147582   976769023   225310721    5  Extended 
/dev/sdb5       526147584   976769023   225310720   8e  Linux LVM

dude@machine:~$ df -T
Filesystem                  Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ext4     197401876 13355496 173995820   8% /
none                        tmpfs            4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                        devtmpfs  16428232        4  16428228   1% /dev
tmpfs                       tmpfs      3288660     1580   3287080   1% /run
none                        tmpfs         5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                        tmpfs     16443284    19692  16423592   1% /run/shm
none                        tmpfs       102400       44    102356   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                   ext2        240972    51593    176938  23% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home ext4     221638340 24327232 186029496  12% /home
/home/dude/.Private          ecryptfs 221638340 24327232 186029496  12% /home/dude
```

Comment: A note about terminology: In your case, `/home` (and `/` and swap) are not partitions; they're *logical volumes.* Given the other information you presented, it's clear what you meant, but in another context it might not have been, and you might have gotten an incorrect answer as a result of using the terms incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use `fdisk`/`parted`/etc. to create a partition in the currently empty space
2. Use `pvcreate` to create a physical volume on the new partition.
3. Use `vgextend` to add the new physical volume to you current volume group, or `vgcreate` create a new volume group
4. Use `lvextend` to extend the logical volume of `/home` (with `-r`, so that the filesystem gets extended too). You'll want to unmount the partition before doing this.

You can do both 1 and 2 in a single step using GParted (right click free space, format as `lvm2 pv`). The third and fourth step needs to be run using the respective commands.

Comment: It's also possible to do the LVM management (steps 2, 3, and 4) with a GUI, such as `system-config-lvm`. Note that it is possible to expand the size of an ext2/3/4 filesystem even if it's mounted, so it's actually not necessary to umount it first. (Backing up first is always advisable when doing low-level disk maintenance, though.)

Comment: @RodSmith `lvextend` runs an `fsck`, which is why I recommended unmounting. I suppose skipping `-r` and using `resize2fs` might be better.

Comment: What I actually did was to move all data off of /home after switching to a user with a home directory that wasn't in /home, and then I removed the logical and physical volume using lvm gui.  Then I used fcdisk to remove/recreate partition. I recreated physical and logical partition using lvm again.

Comment: Question: Did I miss a trick?  I note that I don't have a phase where I create a file system but I think that was done by one of the UI's.  How can I verify?

Comment: @user447607 try `sudo parted -l`, or use the Disks program. Though, I do think you missed a bunch of tricks when you recreated the lvm volumes instead of extending them, sort of defeating the purpose of lvm there.

Comment: @muro Well, I didn't like the idea of having two underlying partitions on the same drive if I was just going to chop them up anyway. Thought it might be problematic later on.